# No simulators available. Please install Xcode and an iOS simulator to preview your project

Tags: ios-simulator, deco

In attempting to use the IDE Deco, for the first time (A IDE for React.js) I received the following error:

> 'No simulators available.',
>   'Please install Xcode and an iOS simulator to preview your project.'

I installed xcode. It's in file:

```
Macintosh HD < Applications < xcode-beta
```

I installed command line tools.  According to command line prompt below, they are located in

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

.

```
[redacted] at MacBook-Air-2 in ~
$  xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
[redacted] at MacBook-Air-2 in ~
$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer 
directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools 
instance
[redacted] at MacBook-Air-2 in ~
$
```

Answer (score 2):

1. run xcode at least once, and install command line tools
2. In console type:

   ```
   $ which xcrun
   // /usr/bin/xcrun
   ```

Then type:

```
$ xcrun --version
// xcrun version 33.
```

Then type:

```
$ xcrun simctl list
// == Device Types ==
```

Then:

open Xcode (top menu):

> Xcode > Preferences > Location

there’s a dropdown for Command Line Tools.  Make sure something is selected there.

Quit your IDE. Restart your IDE.  It should work.  These are the steps that worked for me.

I found these instructions  in the Slack group for Deco.  Posting them on SO for easier access.  The link to the thread: https://decoslack.slack.com/archives/C0NB152SH/p1476392009000521

Comment: Xcode > Preferences > Location
And select the Xcode command line tool
this worked for me